# How can I reference a Queue from a process that won't break when I export the solution?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have some processes that create tasks and put them in to queues by creating a Queue Item entity. Since queues are not included in the solution, when I export from dev and import to test the processes have errors and aren't activated. I have to go through these processes, update the references to the queues, and activate the processes.

Is there a way to reference queues from processes that won't break when I export and import to another environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Queue entity is not Solution-aware, thus you cannot preserve the link during export/import.

The easiest way around this is to ensure that the Primary Key Guid(`Queue.Id`) of the Queue is the same in each organization. The simplest way to do this is to follow [these procedures from Gonzalo Ruiz](http://gonzaloruizcrm.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-prevent-broken-workflow.html).

An alternative is to create your queues in each environment programatically so that you can control the `Queue.Id` value.

```cs
public static Guid CreateQueue(ServerConnection.Configuration serverConfig, 
Guid id, string name) 
    { 
        using (OrganizationServiceProxy serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serverConfig.OrganizationUri, 
                                                               serverConfig.HomeRealmUri, 
                                                               serverConfig.Credentials, 
                                                               serverConfig.DeviceCredentials)) 
        { 
            IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)serviceProxy; 

            Entity newQ = new Entity("queue"); 
            newQ.Id = id; 
            newQ["name"] = name; 

            Guid newqueueid = service.Create(newQ); 

            return newqueueid; 
        } 
    }
```

This code sample is from [Deploying Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and CRM Online Solutions from Development through Test and Production Environments](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27824) which I highly recommend to any Dynamics CRM developers.